# Appending contents of a php file (html w/php) to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I append the contents of a php file (mix of html and php) into an existing div?

I have this div defined which loads three different php files.  But this is very slow because each php retrieves many items with http.  I'd like to have the first php `<?php require("readenglish.php"); ?>` then load the others asynchronously afterwards.  I tried a $.get() but that does not load the php content.

Here is the div.

```
<div id="readings">

    <?php require("readenglish.php"); ?>
    <!-- ?php require("readfrench.php"); ? --> <!-- EDITED OUT DON'T WANT THIS -->
    <!-- ?php require("readspanish.php"); ? --> <!--  -->

</div>
```

Here is the script that loads the php files.

```
<!--  EDIT  WANT THIS INSTEAD OF WHAT IS COMMENTED OUT ABOVE -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){    
    $.get("readfrench.php",function(data){
        $("#readings").append(data);
    },'html');

    $.get("readspanish.php",function(data){
        $("#readings").append(data);
    },'html');    
    });

</script>
```

Here is a sample php file.

```
<?php 

    $todayfeast = date("Ymd");

    $ctitlefe = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=AM&content=FR';
    $creadfe = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=AM&content=FR';

    if ( $curl_exists ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitlefe);        
        $titlefe = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadfe);      
        $readfe = curl_exec($ch);
    }

?>
    <div id="readf" class="tabbertab">
        <h2>First Reading</h2>

        <div id='titlefe' class='rtitle'>
        <?php echo $titlefe; ?>
        </div>
        <div id='readfe' class='rtext'>
        <?php echo $readfe; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The php file loads the contents retrieved into variables which are passed to html elements.  These elements must be appended to the div shown at the top.

Is there a different way to call $.get()?  Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you are already loading the stuff via ajax and stuffing it into an element. So what is the problem?

Comment: @user823527  verify your PHP code. Is it fine? .

Comment: @Tejs Updated the question to show what I want.  The ajax doesn't send the content.  The same content loads if I place it directly within the `<?php ?>`.  I'd like to have the $.get() work or have a different way of doing the same, i.e. make an ajax call to the .php asynchronously.

Comment: @Tejs  @ngen Seems like the `$.get()` is retrieving the data from the php file. But the call to .append() doesn't seem to add it to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does work. Seems that the tabber plug-in cannot be added in jscript it must be on the page initially. If it is added in javascript the element isn't drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Your JScript is working fine.  Only thing i couldn't figure out is the PHP code. Is it outputting the correct doc  with your code?. Here's the code i tried. and it's working.

`PHP` :

```
<?php 

    $todayfeast = date("Ymd");

    $ctitlefe = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=AM&content=FR';
    $creadfe = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=AM&content=FR';



    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$ctitlefe);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $titlefe= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$creadfe);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $readfe= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    


?>
    <div id="readf" class="tabbertab">
        <h2>First Reading</h2>

        <div id='titlefe' class='rtitle'>
        <?php echo $titlefe; ?>
        </div>
        <div id='readfe' class='rtext'>
        <?php echo $readfe; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: you dont need to append the markup in the callback when you are using `load`. Thats the whole point of using load.

Comment: Oh. I missed that. But i'm thinking that he has some PHP problems. I was checking into that. :)

Comment: The php works fine. My question was how to not put everything in the `<?php ?>` and load it instead with ajax.  Also, I only call `curl_init()` and `curl_close()` once for the php file. In between I make several calls to `curl_exec`. Is that wrong?

Comment: @user823527  The script which you have used will get the contents and add it to the existing content of #readings  . Just like you want. I am not understanding which part is not working for you?. Can you be a bit more clear.

Comment: @user823527 Try doing the same without that specific readf and tabbertab class on that  div in the page which is loaded